# Sharepoint application file structure?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is there any source which explains SharePoint application's file structures?

I want to develop Silverlight, WebPart, WebSolutions to SharePoint. But simply would you explain the file structures of these solutions?

1. Elements.xml :
2. key.snk :
3. Features (Folder) :
4. Package (Folder) :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest these two sessions which explain this:

- [Developer Patterns to Integrate Microsoft Silverlight 3.0 with
  Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://bryantlikes.com/ct.ashx?id=d8f512f8-1860-49fb-9d26-234aaedacd95&url=http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/P09-05)
- [Developing Solutions for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 Using the
  Client Object Model](http://bryantlikes.com/ct.ashx?id=d8f512f8-1860-49fb-9d26-234aaedacd95&url=http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/PR07)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/ee513147) course before starting, it's short but informative. Questions you asked described in modules 2,3 and 5